# Problem with Reddit command on discord.js bot

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to put a cursed image command in my discord.js bot but it keeps coming up with this error

```
got('https://www.reddit.com/r/madlads/random/.json').then(response => {
^

ReferenceError: got is not defined
```

Here is the code

```
if(command === "cursed") {

        got('https://www.reddit.com/r/cursedimages/random/.json').then(response => {
                let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
            var image = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
            let permalink = content[0].data.children[0].data.permalink;
            let memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            let memeImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
            let memeTitle = content[0].data.children[0].data.title;
            let memeUpvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.ups;
            let memeNumComments = content[0].data.children[0].data.num_comments;
            const cursedembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTitle(content[0].data.children[0].data.title)
                .setURL(`${memeUrl}`)
                .setImage(image)
                .setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`)
                .setTimestamp()

            message.channel.send(cursedembed);
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed `get` and not `got`?

Comment: I've tried both of those and both come up with that error

Comment: what if you try `fetch` instead of `get`?

Comment: It still says undefined

Comment: Do you have `node-fetch` as one of your packages?

Comment: I don't believe so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have `node-fetch` as one of your packages, you won't be able to use the `fetch` function. In order to use this package, you'll have to follow three steps.

1. Install `node-fetch`. This can be done by running `npm i node-fetch` in your project directory.
2. Import `node-fetch` into your code. This can be done by having `const fetch = require('node-fetch');` at the top of your code file, similar to your discord.js import.
3. Replace `got` with `fetch`.

After that, you should be able to use `fetch` in order to download web content and post reddit content on discord.